# How to Insert A Column With In a Range if Rows Using EPplus?

Tags: c#, epplus, epplus-4

Any one tell me how can I insert a column with in a range of rows? I know the below code will insert a column but I need it for a range of rows.

I didn't find and documentation for this in internet.

```
mainSheets.InsertColumn(1, 1);
```

Comment: I think you have to manually move to the right columns for that range of rows.

Answer (score 0):

I did a lot of research Epplus don't that that kind of option. You have use alternate one.